# What is the difference between spy and stub?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, sinon

I have just started using `sinon.js` and I am completely stumped with the terminology. I have used stubs where in the `subview's` render methods are stubbed out . But the explanation of the **spy** is not clear to me. Can anyone explain what exactly is the difference between these two ?

Also was wondering what the approach would be if I want to test if a new model has been added to a collection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not super-familiar with `sinon.js`, but since these are general TDD terms and not sinon-specific ones, I think I can still answer your quesiton.

The main difference is that a stub exists purely to "get through the code"; the stub itself doesn't do anything except hold dummy values and methods.

Spies on the other hand are stubs that check the values that get put in them, or the methods that get called on them.  In other words, the main difference between the two is assert statements: stubs have none, while spies have some (or else they store values for asserts elsewhere in your test code).

In other words:

```
var Stub = Backbone.Model.extend();
var stub = new Stub({value: 'test value'});
// This can be fed to any view for testing

var Spy = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('change:value', this.handleValueChange);
    },
    handleValueChange: function(value) {
        assert(!isNaN(value));
    };
    value: 'test value'
});
var spy = new Spy({value: 'test value'});
// This can be fed to any view for testing AND it ensures that,
// if that view sets its "value", that that value is a number
```

Oh, and to answer:

> > Also was wondering what the approach would be if I want to test if a new model has been added to a collection?

Again, without getting in to Sinon specifically, there are two obvious places where you can "spy" on the model: the model itself, and its collection.

Either you can add an event handler to (or hard-wire in to a test method on) your model which checks `this.collection` to determine whether/which collection its been added to.  Conversely, you could bind an event or overwrite a method on the collection itself, and check `this.models`.

Comment: @machineghost.. thanks for the reply.. I was trying to stub the handler that was bound to the event listener but still I was not able to check for the modified collection. What is the correct approach here.. using a spy or a stub

Comment: Generally stubs are better, because simpler solutions are better.  With stubs you just: 1. build a stub, 2. pass it to something, 3. assert against the result; simple.  You only want to use spies: A) when you have to (because what you're testing isn't exposed to your test code), or B) when it's more convenient (eg. because you're doing a bunch of related tests that all do similar assertions against the same stub object) ... but all of this seems irrelevant: it sounds like your real issue is that you are "not able to check for the modified collection".  Can you please explain that further?

Comment: I have a listener in place for `add` new collections. I created a stub for this and I am trying to check the length of the collection after this event is fired. It still shows be the same number before and after it is fired.

Comment: I think I figured out what exactly was happening after a lot of debugging .. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help; sometimes you just need to "get your hands dirty" with the debugger :-)